# Powershell Session to one remote host then on to another

Tags: session, powershell

Is there a way to use Powershell to remote onto one machine (let's called it hub) and then from within that session remote onto another (a "spoke")? I need to connect to the hub touchdown server in our VPN before I can connect on to another machine.

Or is there another way to proxy the session via the hub machine?

From within the session to the HUB I can create the new PSSession, but I get an error when trying to enter it:

```
[HUB]: PS C:\Users\idlemind\Documents> New-PSSession remotehost.domain.com -Credential idlemind@domain.com

 Id Name            ComputerName    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
  1 Session1        remotehost.d... Opened        Microsoft.PowerShell     Available


[HUB]: PS C:\Users\idlemind\Documents> Enter-PSSession 1
Enter-PSSession : You are currently in a Windows PowerShell PSSession and cannot use the Enter-PSSession cmdlet to enter another PSSession.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enter-PSSession], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoteHostDoesNotSupportPushRunspace,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand
```

Comment: What OS is that "hub" machine running?

Comment: It's running Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to enable Multihop Remoting on Hub.
`Enable-WSManCredSSP –Role Client –DelegateComputer spoke`

And this on Spoke. `Enable-WSManCredSSP –Role Server`

Please read

1. http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/04/04/enabling-multihop-remoting.aspx
2. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj853299.aspx
3. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since your runnig a 2012 server, I'd investigate installing Powershell Web Access on that 'Hub' machine.  It will give you very fine-grained access control, and act as a "gateway" to remote sessions on other machines once your are connected to it.

Comment: Powershell Web Access looks useful, but I'm a bit put off by the browser based interface. I'd really like to use the normal Powershell Prompt on my local machine, preferably via ConEmu

Comment: I don't know a way to get around the restriction disallowing chained sessions.